# Manipulation on a file with 750 million records

Tags: database, csv, data-manipulation

I need to make column based manipulation on a csv file of 46 GB containing 750 million records. I have split the data from the large file to individual csv files, but requirement is to make it available based on a column.

Total no of columns in the file are 6.

Comment: Hi Meht4409 - Process is set up your database with correct column types, import the records, manipulate with SQL. What have you tried and what are you stuck on, at the moment there isn't a question here so you may need to update your question so we can help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to ask a good question, at the moment this question may get closed.

Comment: `make it available based on column ?` can you please clarify